# Column name issue from csv to MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have an issue with column names when I transfer csv file into MySQL workbench. Column name on csv file is like "Type of flight" and MySQL gives an error when I SELECT that particular column.
What can I do?

I tried to put underscore _ between words on the column name but it did not work.

Comment: I woudl guess you will have to wrap that column name in backtics as it has a space init so `SELECT \`Type of flight\`, otherCol FROM ....`

Comment: It is always best to make database/table/column names be a string without spaces like `type_of_flight` and stick to lower case as well